# Segmention fault because not using triple pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic

Following code should copy a matrix in another one. But I get a segmentation fault: core dump. xmalloc function allocates the array, init initializes it, copy copies it and xfree frees the space. I think how I've utilize memcpy is the error, how can I fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int xmalloc(int **p, int dim1, int dim2);
void xfree(int **p, int dim1);
void init(int **p, int dim1, int dim2);
void copy(int **source, int **destination, int dim1, int dim2);

int main(void)
{
    int **p1, **p2, dim1, dim2;

    scanf("%d\n%d",&dim1,&dim2);

    if(!xmalloc(p1,dim1,dim2))
        return -1;

    if(!xmalloc(p2,dim1,dim2))
        return -1;

    init(p1,dim1,dim2);

    copy(p1,p2,dim1,dim2);

    xfree(p1,dim1);
    xfree(p2,dim2);

    return 0;
}

int xmalloc(int **p, int dim1, int dim2)
{
    int i;

    p=malloc(dim1*sizeof(int*));
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        perror("Malloc");
        return 0;
    }
    for(i=0; i<dim1; i++)
    {
        p[i]=malloc(dim2*sizeof(int));
        if(p[i]==NULL)
        {
            perror("Malloc");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void xfree(int **p, int dim1)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<dim1; i++)
        free(p[i]);
    free(p);
}

void init(int **p, int dim1, int dim2)
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<dim1; i++)
        for(j=0; j<dim2; j++)
            p[i][j]=i*dim2+j;
}

void copy(int **source, int **destination, int dim1, int dim2)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<dim1; i++)
    {
        memcpy(destination[i],source[i],dim2*sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

What is the error?
Please, allow me to use scanf for simplify this program.

**Solution:**

-use of triple pointers

-pass correct parameter to xfree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think how I've utilize memcpy is the error

No, that's not the problem. The problem is your misunderstanding of double and triple pointers.

Currently, the assignment of double pointer `p` inside `xmalloc` has no effect, because pointers are passed by value. After the call of `xmalloc` both your `p1` and `p2` continue pointing to undefined locations, causing segfaults on dereference.

In order to fix this problem your `xmalloc` function

```
int xmalloc(int **p, int dim1, int dim2);
```

should look like this:

```
int xmalloc(int ***p, int dim1, int dim2);
```

The assignment inside it

```
p=malloc(dim1*sizeof(int*));
```

should be

```
*p=malloc(dim1*sizeof(int*));
```

and the call should look like

```
if(!xmalloc(&p1,dim1,dim2))
    return -1;

if(!xmalloc(&p2,dim1,dim2))
    return -1;
```

Comment: @SimoneBonato Because of the same reason that you need to pass a pointer instead of an `int` to `scanf`. Otherwise, the assignment inside `xmalloc` has zero effect.

Comment: @SimoneBonato Your other functions look fine.

Comment: If, inserting 5 and 8 as input, I add, for example, `printf("%d",p2[1][1]);` after `copy` function I receive an other core dump.

Comment: @SimoneBonato Did you put parentheses around `*p` inside `xmalloc`? I.e. `(*p)[i]=malloc(dim2*sizeof(int));` and `if((*p)[i]==NULL)`?

Comment: Yes, I have. In init function `printf("%d",p[i-1][j-1]);` works.

Comment: @SimoneBonato `printf("%d",p2[1][1])` works for me. You should pass `dim1` in the second call to `xfree` ([demo](http://ideone.com/ZPj8dk)).

Comment: Thank you, it works. How is possible that changing parameter of a next function there is no core dump?

Comment: @SimoneBonato The core dump happens in the next function, not in `printf`. It's just that it happens so quickly that whatever `printf` has printed does not get a chance to get printed.